# Binding to a CollectionViewSource with expander style

Tags: wpf, binding, collectionviewsource

I have a `CollectionViewSource` bound to an `ObservableCollection` of my `ViewModels`. I then have a `style` on the `GroupItem` which has an `expander` in it. I want to be able to have a 'collapse all' and an 'expand all' on the group headers, but am having trouble binding to the `isExpanded` on the `expander` in the `ControlTemplate`.  I have this code:

```
      <Style x:Key="GroupStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding Path=**????**}" Template="{StaticResource DAExpander}">
                            <Expander.Header>
                                <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" x:Name="scItemIcon" Source="./groupIcon.ico" Height="18" Width="18"/>
                                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding Name}"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="4,0,6,0" />
                                </DockPanel>
                            </Expander.Header>
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </Expander>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

I have an IsExpanded property on my view model but i cant figure out how to access it.  I have found examples such as:

```
<Expander IsExpanded="{Binding Path=Items[0].IsExpanded}" 
<Expander IsExpanded="{Binding Path=Name.IsExpanded}"
```

None of which seem to work. Is there a way to accomplish this or do i need to take a different approach?

**Edit**: more xaml, and view model code:

```
           <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCVS}}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItmesTemplate}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemChildStyle}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" >
                <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupStyle}" />
                    <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource Group2Style}" />
                </ListBox.GroupStyle>
            </ListBox>



public class ItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {   
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public string SubGroupName{ get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public bool IsExpanded {get; set;}
    }
```

Comment: Post more code about ViewModel and more XAML

Comment: Let me know if there is other code you would like to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this without binding by adding an event to the click on my 'Expand all' button

```
private void expandAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get each listBoxItem by index from the listBox
    for (int i = 0; i < MyListBox.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)MyListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);

        // find its parents expander
        var exp = FindParent<Expander>(item);

        if (exp != null)
        {
            //if its not null expand it and see if it has a parent expander
            exp.IsExpanded = true;
            exp = FindParent<Expander>(exp);
            if (exp != null)
                exp.IsExpanded = true;
        }

    }
}
```

The FindParent function is a helper that walks up the visual tree looking for the control specified starting at the control you pass in.